# ArangoDB Setup in Development

Tags: arangodb

How can I setup (setup phase on the manifest.json) a new application in development mode? (running arangod with --javascript.dev-app-path)

I want to create the collections I need during development through this script.

Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in development mode the setup phase will automatically be triggered on each request, teardown not.
If you want to call it explicitly you can use the arangosh and issue the following commands:

Setup:

```
arangosh> fm.devSetup(<your apps folder name>)
```

Teardown

```
arangosh> fm.devTeardown(<your apps folder name>)
```